# DateTimeIndex.to_period raises a ValueError exception for many offset aliases

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to solve a very simple problem, but am running into a wall.
I have a DateTimeIndex based on a simple dataframe like follows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
     index=pd.date_range(
        start='2017-01-01', 
        end='2017-03-04', closed=None), 
     data=np.arange(63), columns=['val']).rename_axis(index='date')

In [179]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[179]: 
            val
date           
2017-01-01    0
2017-01-02    1
2017-01-03    2
2017-01-04    3
2017-01-05    4
...         ...
2017-02-28   58
2017-03-01   59
2017-03-02   60
2017-03-03   61
2017-03-04   62

[63 rows x 1 columns]
```

I wish to summarize the values by periods of weekly, semi-monthly, monthly etc.
So I tried:

```
In [180]: df.to_period('W').groupby('date').sum()                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[180]: 
                       val
date                      
2016-12-26/2017-01-01    0
2017-01-02/2017-01-08   28
2017-01-09/2017-01-15   77
2017-01-16/2017-01-22  126
2017-01-23/2017-01-29  175
2017-01-30/2017-02-05  224
2017-02-06/2017-02-12  273
2017-02-13/2017-02-19  322
2017-02-20/2017-02-26  371
2017-02-27/2017-03-05  357
```

That works fine for offset aliases like Y, M, D, W, T, S, L, U, N.
But fails for SM, SMS and others listed here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

It raises a ValueError exception:

> ```
> In [181]: df.to_period('SMS').groupby('date').sum()               
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies._period_str_to_code()
>
> KeyError: 'SMS-15'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-181-6779559a0596> in <module>
> ----> 1 df.to_period('SMS').groupby('date').sum()
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py
> in to_period(self, freq, axis, copy)    8350         axis =
> self._get_axis_number(axis)    8351         if axis == 0:
> -> 8352             new_data.set_axis(1, self.index.to_period(freq=freq))    8353         elif axis == 1:   
> 8354             new_data.set_axis(0,
> self.columns.to_period(freq=freq))
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py
> in f(self, *args, **kwargs)
>      91         def _create_delegator_method(name):
>      92             def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
> ---> 93                 return self._delegate_method(name, *args, **kwargs)
>      94 
>      95             f.__name__ = name
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimelike.py
> in _delegate_method(self, name, *args, **kwargs)
>     811 
>     812     def _delegate_method(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
> --> 813         result = operator.methodcaller(name, *args, **kwargs)(self._data)
>     814         if name not in self._raw_methods:
>     815             result = Index(result, name=self.name)
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py
> in to_period(self, freq)    1280             freq =
> get_period_alias(freq)    1281 
> -> 1282         return PeriodArray._from_datetime64(self._data, freq, tz=self.tz)    1283     1284     def to_perioddelta(self, freq):
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/period.py
> in _from_datetime64(cls, data, freq, tz)
>     273         PeriodArray[freq]
>     274         """
> --> 275         data, freq = dt64arr_to_periodarr(data, freq, tz)
>     276         return cls(data, freq=freq)
>     277 
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/period.py
> in dt64arr_to_periodarr(data, freq, tz)
>     914         data = data._values
>     915 
> --> 916     base, mult = libfrequencies.get_freq_code(freq)
>     917     return libperiod.dt64arr_to_periodarr(data.view("i8"), base, tz), freq
>     918 
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies.get_freq_code()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies.get_freq_code()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies.get_freq_code()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies._period_str_to_code()
>
> ValueError: Invalid frequency: SMS-15
> ```

I am using python 3.6.5, pandas version '0.25.1'

Comment: Yes, it appears that `to_period` is not converting SMS no SM properly.  However, you can avoid this problem by using `resample` as @Jezrael points out.

Comment: Thanks @Jezrael. Both the suggested options will suffice for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) here:

```
print (df.resample('W').sum())
            val
date           
2017-01-01    0
2017-01-08   28
2017-01-15   77
2017-01-22  126
2017-01-29  175
2017-02-05  224
2017-02-12  273
2017-02-19  322
2017-02-26  371
2017-03-05  357
```

---

```
print (df.resample('SM').sum())
            val
date           
2016-12-31   91
2017-01-15  344
2017-01-31  555
2017-02-15  663
2017-02-28  300

print (df.resample('SMS').sum())
            val
date           
2017-01-01   91
2017-01-15  374
2017-02-01  525
2017-02-15  721
2017-03-01  242
```

Alternatives with `groupby` and [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
print (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).sum())
print (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='SM')).sum())
print (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='SMS')).sum())
```